# ASP.NET MVC 5 - One View for multiple action methods?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

In my application I need three views that shows the same data :Employee details data toghether with employee job positions (job history). They differ only for some buttons.

AS you can see in the images below the Details view shows data and the only available action is "go back". The second is the EditView. Editing, here, means only add a new job position. Other employee data are not editable.
The third view is for changing the employee state (Enabled, Disabled, Deleted) : buttons in the footer are visible\hidden based on current employee state.

**Details**

[image]

**Edit**

[image]

**ChangeState**

[image]

Do you think is a good option to have one view for all three methods (Detail, Edit, ChangeState) ?

The ViewModel passed to the view should have properties to be evaluated in order to show\hide buttons.
For example : CurrentState (enabled, disabled, deleted), Action (ShowDetail, Edit, ChangeState).

I was also thinking to use two partial views for employee details and job position sections.

Answer (score 1):

Have you cosidered using Partial Views?

Controller:

```
[Route("no-partial")]
public IActionResult Index()
{
    var model = new CustomModel()
    {
        Name = "Home",
    };

    return View("~/Views/Home/Index.cshtml", model);
}

[Route("with-partial")]
public IActionResult IndexWithPartialView()
{
    var model = new CustomModel()
    {
        Name = "Home",
        PartialViewPath = "~/Views/Shared/_MyPartialView.cshtml"
    };

    return View("~/Views/Home/Index.cshtml", model);
}
```

View:

```
@model CustomModel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
}

<div class="text-center">
    <h1>Welcome to homepage</h1>
    @if (Model.PartialViewPath != null)
    {
        @await Html.PartialAsync(Model.PartialViewPath)
    }
</div>
```

Partial View:

```
<div>
    <h1>Hello from Partial View</h1>
</div>
```

Results:

https://localhost:7230/no-partial

```
<main b-bddmc6yalx="" role="main" class="pb-3">
    <div class="text-center">
        <h1>Welcome to homepage</h1>
    </div>
</main>
```

https://localhost:7230/with-partial

```
<main b-bddmc6yalx="" role="main" class="pb-3">
    <div class="text-center">
        <h1>Welcome to homepage</h1>

        <div>
            <h1>Hello from Partial View</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</main>
```

For more info about Partial Views, please see the following: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/partial?view=aspnetcore-7.0

This is in my opinion not the best practice. I would recommend making multiple smaller partial views and then just building the view with them. What do I mean by that is the following:

```
Create.cshtml:
- Partial_Form
- Partial_CreateButtons
- Partial_Form2

Edit.cshtml:
- Partial_Form
- Partial_EditButtons
- Partial_Form2
- Partial_DeleteButtons

Detail.cshtml:
- Partial_Form
- Partial_Form2
- Partial_DetailButtons
```

You will have 3 views, however the content will be built from these Partial Views that you will 'hard-code' into your View. Therefore, whenever you will need to edit something, you will be editing the smaller component/view rather than the huge generic View.